# How can I get my FTP client - Transmit - to keep the file's modified date after a transfer?

Tags: ftp, date-modified

Questions says it all.  I've looked in site and app prefs, but can't find anything.  Seems like a no brainer for such a nice FTP app, so I gotta think I'm just missing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

I was looking for this same answer myself.  I eventually found this in an FAQ list on the Panic site:

> Choose Transmit → Preferences →
>   Advanced, then click the Advanced
>   Server Settings button. Then, check
>   the **Preserve modification dates** option
>   next to the server in question.

In my case, there were no server settings, just a "default" setting, but since I always wanted the modification dates preserved (in order to sync changes to web sites from different machines), that was fine for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I needed to do this in Panic's Coda editor. The settings are in the same place in Coda as they are in Transmit. Thanks.

Comment: This really ought to be the default.

Answer (score 3):

Can you put the files into a tar, do the ftp transfer and then untar? This way the timestamps will be preserved.

Comment: hmmm, interesting idea, but don't think would work for me as I synch often and with large sites.  taring all the files kind of defeats the purpose of the selective sync.  Thanks for the idea tho.

Comment: can you use scp instead? it has a -p option to preserve timestamps?

Comment: haven't seen any gui scp clients that do synching, and don't think you can do it via the command line... can you?